# Identity server multiple provider

Tags: c#, identityserver4

Hi I am trying to add multiple providers

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddIdentityProviders(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var identityProvidersOptions = configuration.GetSection(identityProvidersSectionName)
                                                .Get<IdentityProviderOptions[]>();

    var ipFactory = new IdentityProviderControlFactory();

    foreach (var identityProvider in identityProvidersOptions)
    {
        if ( Enum.TryParse(identityProvider.Discriminator, out IdentityProviderTypes accessControlType) 
            && accessControlType != IdentityProviderTypes.None )
        {
            builder = ipFactory.GetIdentityProviderService(accessControlType)
                                .Register(builder, configuration, identityProvider);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    return builder;
}
```

in settings I got two providers and then for each 'register' method is lanuched:

```
AuthenticationBuilder Register(AuthenticationBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration, IdentityProviderOptions identityProviderOptions)
```

which inside creates a singleton like that :

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
builder.AddOpenIdConnect(identityProviderOptions.Name, identityProviderOptions.Name, _ => { });
```

and in the seconds one like that

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureIBMOptions>();
builder.AddOpenIdConnect(identityProviderOptions.Name, identityProviderOptions.Name, _ => { });
```

seems this is a problem because seems only one provider can be registerd and seconds one only overides some values, so how can it be achived to register multiple providers for identity server?

If I add two identityProviders I got exception

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'The payload was invalid.'
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple providers?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg you should ask the client :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know allready this is related with CallbackPath and SignedOutCallbackPath, for every provider has to be different, and I am looking a way now to override those endpoints.

"The specific CallbackPath and SignedOutCallbackPath you would configure in the target identity provider as allowed sites. So when the target identity provider posts back it would post back to route you have configured in CallbackPath and Oidc middleware will pick the correct configuration to u"